# Connect to Cloud SQL Database Using mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysql

Ive been locally developing a site primarily in php and have been using mysqli_connect

```
$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "admin";
$dbPassword = "****";
$dbName = "db_name";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

I later refer to $conn when making a connection such as

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

I have already cloned my local database and added a connection whitelisting the VM i will be contacting the database from.

Im moving in the direction of having the database be cloud sql from google and am overwhelmed with the process of connecting my VM (live site) to the cloud sql database when retrieving content and updating the DB. Is there a simple solution where i pass the ip address, username, password and db name? How can I achieve a connection?

Comment: It isn't clear what your question means with the information you've given us. Simply update the code where the connect is to use different credentials. If that is in a separate file modify it to accept and use the 4 pieces of information that will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your config connection must be like :

```
$dbServername = "cloudipad:port";
$dbUsername = "username";
$dbPassword = "password";
$dbName = "db_name";
```

Comment: FYI the [mysqli constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) of which `mysqli_connect` is an alias has the port has a separate argument from the host. I'm not saying your way won't work, but I would recommend using arguments as defined in the docs.

Comment: Port is also not necessary if it's using the default 3306.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to include the port.